# Package ... is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and whenever I try to install some packages it throws some error message. I don't know how to solve.

I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade update` all things but still the issue persists.

Error message while installing packages :

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package google-chrome-stable is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package  'google-chrome-stable'  has no installation candidate
```

I'm getting this error while try to install packages like `virt-manager`, `qemu`, `qemu-kvm`, `bridge-utils`, `libvirt-bin` etc...

Can you please guide me on how to resolve this error?

Comment: You'll have to specify the exact command you are running for a specify install and the exact error message you are getting so that we can identify the problem with the specific package.  If you get one resolved and installed, you might find that using the same steps for correctly installing a specific package might work for the other package you're having problems installing.

Comment: sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package google-chrome-stable is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'google-chrome-stable' has no installation candidate

Comment: If you haven't touched the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, try `sudo apt-get update`. If it fails fetching the information from the repos, you probably have a network or routing issue. If it works, go to `software & updates` to add more software sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apt-get` command will search the repositories and install a package from the repositories.  The `google-chrome-stable` package that you referred to in your comment isn't available in the Ubuntu's default repository.  You can add other repositories to your system.  The installation of those packages will depend on the particular repository that you have added to your system.

You can add Google's `google-chrome` using their official install from their site using: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

This download will give you their latest version which will be a file similar to:

```
google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

You can install this with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

This will install the Chrome and also make it available in your local `apt-get` installs and updates.

This will remove your error message `Package package_name is not available` for `google-chrome-stable`.  You would have to do similar steps depending on the other packages that you are trying to install that don't currently have a package by that name in your installed repositories.